# Searching for a reference book in logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, book-recommendation

I am attending a mathematical logic course and I need one or more books to be my references. The professor did not suggest any book in particulare and this is why I am writing here.
The topics of the course is

1. Formalization of first order languages
2. Trees
3. Naturale deduction system
4. Intuitionistic and classical logic
5. Proving classical non-deducibility; truth tables
6. Completness and decidibility of classical propositional calculus
7. Sequent calculus
8. Cut elimination theorem and application
9. Herbrand and Hilbert-Ackerman's theorem
10. Semantic of evaluation and completness
11. Skolem form and risolution in classical logic

If you could suggest me some books on those topics I will be very pleased.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No book springs to mind which covers just your listed topics. And indeed, it is difficult to make recommendations without knowing too the level of mathematical sophistication expected in the course. But take a look at this Study Guide: https://www.logicmatters.net/resources/pdfs/TeachYourselfLogic2017.pdf This will at least give you pointers to reliable/accessible books which you can extract material from.